# Can we please change the "scrummaster" tag to be hyphenated like other similar tags?

Tags: support, tags

### TL;DR

The current [scrummaster](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrummaster) tag should be converted to [scrum-master](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrum-master), which is more consistent with our existing naming conventions.

### Explanation

Currently, [scrummaster](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrummaster) is a canonical tag. However, other role tags are hyphenated like [product-owner](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-owner), [product-manager](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-manager), and [project-sponsor](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-sponsor). For various reasons, I can't create a synonym for it, and [scrum-master](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrum-master) would be more in line with the way the community has defined other tags over time anyway.

Redefining a tag requires diamond moderator privileges. Ideally, the [scrummaster](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrummaster) tag would just be redefined as hyphenated. In this case, I don't think we need to retain the unhyphenated version, but if we do it should be as a synonym of [scrum-master](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrum-master) and not the other way around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Agree on this, and I love to stick to patterns. It's done!